# Get User to Input range in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to ask the user for a range (for an array) i.e variables start, stop and increment. I am having difficulty asking for each  variable without breaking up my string. So far I have this code:

```
x=numpy.arange(input('Enter Start:'), input('Enter Stop:'),input ('Enter increment:'))
```

However I would like it to read: 'Enter Start, Stop, Increment:' and allow the user to input three numbers e.g. 2, 10, 2 rather than inputting them one at a time.

I would be grateful for any advice

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> start, stop, inc = raw_input('Enter start, stop, increment:').split(',')
Enter start, stop, increment:0, 5, 2
>>> print start, stop, inc
0  5  2
```

Keep in mind that those are strings, use `int` to convert them

Answer (score 1):

The user has to confirm his entry by hitting the ENTER key. `input()` automatically outputs that as a linebreak, so you can't have it all in one line with 3 calls to `input()`. You could use one input and ask for all 3 values:

```
>>> userrange = input("Please input start, stop and increment: ")
Please input start, stop and increment: 1,2,3
>>> userrange
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> makearange = lambda a: np.arange(int(a[0]),int(a[1]),int(a[2]))
>>> x = makearange(raw_input('Enter start,stop,increment: ').split(','))
Enter start,stop,increment: 2,100,10
>>> x
array([ 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92])
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain 'makearange = lambda a:' I am afraid I am new to numpy.

Comment: Sure, the lambda function is part of Python and not numpy (see http://diveintopython.org/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html for more info on them). It means that you can make a call to 'makearange' with an argument (in this case the user input, which it assigns to the variable 'a'), and makarange will then return a numpy.arange object with the start, stop and increment defined by the user (i.e. using the 3 values in the list made from the users input).